# Sending information from IRC Class to WinForm TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm having a problem getting my IRC Client to work. I normally don't use winforms or WPF, I chose WinForms because it was slightly easier to work with, I'm not new to threading, but I have no idea how this works.

**What I'm trying to accomplish in a nutshell:**

1. *Connect to IRC using "SmartIRC4Net"*
2. *Handle IRC Text via simple*
3. *Parsing with the library.  Send all chat and other info to the GUI
           (WinForms)*

**What's the Problem?**

- *All of it. It won't bind to the UI or connect from the IRC Class made in `Program.cs`*

---

**`MainForm.cs:`**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form {
    public MainForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundWorker b = new BackgroundWorker();
        b.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWork1);
        b.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
 } 
 private void bgWork1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
     Program irc = new Program();
     irc.Start();
 }
```

---

**`Program.cs:`**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
 private static extern void ExitProcess(int a);
static MainForm Form1;
public static MainForm form = new MainForm(); // Main Form Controls
[STAThread]
 public static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true); - Ignoring this due to a start error.
    form.Text = "Test"; // Trying to send text, doesn't work
    form.MessageSend.Text = "Test 2"; // Trying to send text, doesn't work.
    MessageHandle(null, "Starting Client!! Welcome" + conf.BaseAdmin, 0);
    GenerateFiles();
    form.Text = "IRC Client Attempting to connect...";
    irc.OnConnected += new EventHandler(OnConnected);
    irc.OnChannelMessage += new IrcEventHandler(OnChanMsg);
    irc.OnQueryMessage += new IrcEventHandler(OnPriv);
    irc.OnJoin += new JoinEventHandler(OnJoined);
    irc.ActiveChannelSyncing = true;
    try {
        irc.Connect(conf.Server, 6667);
    } catch {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error in connecting"); // for debugging
    }
    irc.Listen();
}
public static void MessageHandle(string name, string msg, int type) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string timestamp = now.ToShortTimeString();
    if (type == 0) {
        // Client Message 
        form.MessageSend.Text += String.Format("[{0}]   --- {1}\n\r", timestamp, msg);
    } else if (type == 1) {
        // Private Message
        form.MessageSend.Text += String.Format("[{0}]   <{1}> {2}\n\r", timestamp, name, msg);
    } else if (type == 2) {
        // Regular User Message
        form.MessageSend.Text += String.Format("[{0}]   <{1}> {2}\n\r", timestamp, name, msg);
    } else if (type == 3) {
        // Channel Mod (Operator)
        form.MessageSend.Text += String.Format("[{0}]   <@{1}> {2}\n\r", timestamp, name, msg);
    } else if (type == 4) {
        // Broadcaster (Admin)
        form.MessageSend.Text += String.Format("[{0}]   <~{1}> {2}\n\r", timestamp, name, msg);
    } else if (type == 5) {
        // Bot Admin
        form.MessageSend.Text += String.Format("[{0}]   <+{1}> {2}\n\r", timestamp, name, msg);
    } else if (type == 6) {
        // Channel Action (/me)
        form.MessageSend.Text += String.Format("[{0}]   * {1} {2}\n\r", timestamp, name, msg);
    } else if (type == 7) {
        // Join Channel
        form.MessageSend.Text += String.Format("[{0}]   *** {1} has joined the channel!", timestamp, name);
    } else if (type == 8) {
        // Self Message
        form.MessageSend.Text += String.Format("[{0}]   <{1}> {2}\n\r", timestamp, name, msg);
        irc.SendMessage(SendType.Message, conf.Channel, msg);
    }
}
    #region --- Connection Handler (OnConnected) ---
    public static void OnConnected(object Sender, EventArgs e) {
        try {
            irc.Login(conf.Nick, "Name", 0, conf.Nick);
            irc.RfcJoin(conf.Channel);
            form1.ResetText();
            form1.Text = "IRC.Cli | Connected as " + conf.Nick + " (" + conf.Channel + ")";

            MessageHandle(conf.Nick, null, 7);
            irc.Listen();
        } catch (Exception er) {
            MessageHandle(null, "[Error] : " + er.Message + " " + er.Source, 0);
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Why are you declaring an instance of `Program` in MainForm? `Main` in `Program` is the entry point, you shouldn't be creating a new instance of it from a Form. If you create a new WinForms project and then put all your code in the Form, or even a static class referenced from the Form, you'll save yourself a world of pain

Comment: I'm declaring Main in Program as the entry point. Program.cs is all static, most of the main classes are in Program.cs, I just can't get any of it to function WITH injunction to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you modify a `Console project` by replacing the Console with a Form. One of the major differences between a `WinForm project` and `Console project` is this line

```
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

`Application.Run(Form)` shows the Form, and begins running a standard application message loop, so the Form can react to mouse clicking, repaint itself, etc. Without this line, I don't know what will happen.

> *All of it. It won't bind to the UI...*

My suggestion is creating a new Windows Form project in Visual Studio, and adopt the IRC code into a seperate class.

```
class IRCClient
{
    public event EventHandler OnConnected;
    public event IrcEventHandler OnChannelMessage;
    public event IrcEventHandler OnQueryMessage;
    public event JoinEventHandler OnJoin;
    public bool ActiveChannelSyncing { get; set; }
    ...    
}
```

Then in your MainForm.cs

```
private void bgWork1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{
    IRCClient irc = new IRCClient();
    irc.OnConnected += new EventHandler(OnConnected);
    irc.OnChannelMessage += new IrcEventHandler(OnChanMsg);
    irc.OnQueryMessage += new IrcEventHandler(OnPriv);
    irc.OnJoin += new JoinEventHandler(OnJoined);
    irc.ActiveChannelSyncing = true; 
    irc.Start();
}

private void OnConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}

//and other event handlers
```

And the standard Windows Form entry in `Program.cs`

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

Comment: If all my event handlers are in the MainForm, why and what would I use the IRCClass for?

Comment: Of course the IRC code can be put into the MainForm class.

Comment: Sorry about this, one more question, should I thread the SmartIRC4Net's `irc.Connect(server, port)` or just have it in the current `BackgroundWorker`. Sorry again, I know nothing about WinForms, was working with Consoles for years. When running the connection, I either get `NotConnected` when in the `BackgroundWorker method`, and if I put it in it's own `method` I get no connection.

Comment: Nevermind, it's the server itself I'm connecting too. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: np. You can start another question regarding the `NotConnected` issue, since it is a different problem from the one we discussed in this thread.

Comment: It was the server, it was down. That's all. I thought I messed something up then I caught the `Exception`.